# Matrix inverse, Schur's complement and the chicken or the egg dilemma

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, inverse-function

Suppose

$\textbf{M}=\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{A}&\textbf{B}\\\\ \textbf{C}&\textbf{D}\end{pmatrix}.$

We can compute $\textbf{M}^{-1}$ using (see [here](http://gubner.ece.wisc.edu/notes/BlockMatrixFormulas.pdf)):

$\textbf{M}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\textbf{A}^{-1}+\textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{B}\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{C}\textbf{A}^{-1}&-\textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{B}\textbf{S}^{-1}\\\\ -\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{C}\textbf{A}^{-1}&\textbf{S}^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$, where $\textbf{S} = \textbf{D}-\textbf{C}\textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{B}$

How would one get $\textbf{S}^{-1}$ (i.e. inverting the Schur complement of $\textbf{A}$)?

One way would be to use Woodbury matrix identity, but we would end up with "**the chicken or the egg dilemma**", since $\textbf{S}^{-1}= \textbf{D}^{-1}+\textbf{D}^{-1}\textbf{C}\textbf{T}^{-1}\textbf{B}\textbf{D}^{-1}$ and $\textbf{T}^{-1}= \textbf{A}^{-1}+\textbf{A}^{-1}\textbf{B}\textbf{S}^{-1}\textbf{C}\textbf{A}^{-1}$ (i.e. we need $\textbf{T}^{-1}$ to compute $\textbf{S}^{-1}$ and we need $\textbf{S}^{-1}$ to compute $\textbf{T}^{-1}$).

Is there a way around that?